# RXJS sequence for multiple observables

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I am trying to wrap my head around RXJS and had a quick question on how to tackle the following workflow using observables instead of promises.

Here is the log in workflow in angular 2:

- i look in local storage for JWT. if JWT exists i return the token.
- if not in local storage i check to see the platform. if Android i log into my server using google bearer token, my server returns a JWT (through angular HTTP obserable).
- if not in local storage and the platform is a windows computer i generate a JWT on my server and return (through angular HTTP obserable)
- for the two calls to the server i want to cache the token in local storage before returning the JWT information to the calling function.

I have everything execpt how to do this properly using RXJS, mostly how to chain all of this together. Can i get a quick pseudocode using Observables on how to do this? I basically want to intercept the JWT and store in local storage before moving on in the application (the calling function subscribing to the sequence above)

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer async functions for this task.

```
var jwtPromise = null;

function getJwt() {
  return jwtPromise || (jwtPromise = getJwtNotCached());
}

async function getJwtNotCached() {
  const localJwt = getLocalJwt();
  if (localJwt) {
    return localJwt;
  }
  const newJwt = await fetchJwtByPlatform();
  storeLocalJwt(newJwt);
  return newJwt;
}

async function fetchJwtByPlatform() {
  if (platformIsAndroid()) {
    return await fetchJwtOnAndroid();
  }
  return await fetchJwtOnWindows();
}

...
```

This code will even ensure that no multiple network requests are made if called twice at a time.

Comment: thanks for the response. Would this work with angular 2 HTTP since it returns observables? I can use await on the observable returned by the angular 2 HTTP call?

Comment: @RickyFunkhouser No you cant, but you can `await observable.toPromise();`. That's why I am really sad about angular2 http returning observables.

Comment: ok, i'd like to at least try this using the observables so i can figure out how to use them properly. I can do this with promises but i feel like i'm going around how angular 2 wants me to do things.  Most of the observable examples i can find use a range function on a set of numbers which doesn't really help me. I'd like to find some examples where multiple observables can be merged into a single result (the JWT) while potentially processing the observable response before returning to the calling function. The functions and classes in RXJS are vast and i am totally lost!

Comment: @RickyFunkhouser I am with you, I would be happy to see a nice solution using observables too :) Maybe I will try to put some code together with observables, but I expect it to be awkward, that's why it would be best if somebody else with more experience at observables did so.